# Safari 5 on 10.6 remove 'Add Bookmark' button from location bar

Tags: bookmarks, toolbar, safari-5

My Safari toolbar looks like:

[image]

`< > | (+)__________location bar_____________ | ____google____ |`.

It has Back, Forward, break, Add Bookmark (the +), Location bar, break, Google search bar.

Anyone have a clue how to get the '+' button to disappear?

All I want in the bar is:

`< > | __________location bar_____________ | ____google____ |`.

I had it like this going back to Safari 4 or even further, but now the + is part of the location bar, and I can't remove one without the other. It might've been a `defaults write com.apple.Safari` that I can't remember. Any help would be spectacular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy: right click, select `customize toolbar`, drag a new "add bookmark" button into the bar (to separate the original from the location bar), and then drag the detached + button off to the side (not back into the customize window, I mean like "out of safari") and it'll disappear in a poof of smoke, just how you like it!

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. But it seems to work. +1.